# mix-blend-mode is broken by 3D transformations on page

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms, background-blend-mode

I was fiddling with the `mix-blend-mode` property. Everything works fine until I add something like `transform: perspective(100px)` or any other 3d transformation anywhere on the page, then it breaks completely. The transformation is applied but the blend mode is gone.

I tested on chrome and firefox and on linux and windows and it's the same everywhere, however on a different computer it worked fine (I don't remember what version of chrome it had and was running ubuntu).

Is that something that can be fixed with CSS or is it possibly just a hardware / GPU drivers issue?

I put `background-blend-mode` in tags because the `mix-blend-mode` tag doesn't exist yet, however this property strangely works completely fine and isn't broken by transformations.

Here is a codepen of what I am trying to achieve:
http://codepen.io/vnenkpet/pen/avWvRg

The lightning shouldn't have it's black background flashing with it but should be blended smoothly with the page background.

**EDIT:**

I have just found out that it actually DOES work in Firefox. Is this therefore a chrome bug? 3D Transforms shouldn't break blend mode as far as I know...

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue, except that applying a `mix-blend-mode` (multiply) higher on the page broke my `transform`s lower on the page (using Chrome on Mac). I was able to fix this by applying a `z-index` rule to the `mix-blend-mode` div (don't forget to set a `position`, too).

I'm not entirely sure if this is a bug or if it is expected behavior due to the properties of stacking contexts, though.

Comment: This is the solution for me in chrome 74, because there was a similar problem with mix-blend-mode not working when translate3d transform is on.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is a pretty old thread, but I was having the same issue with janky transforms in Webkit/Blink using the **Masonry Isotope** plugin with a mix-blend-mode overlay on the grid sections until I added the following CSS to the element that was being transformed. **i.e. the masonry grid element**

I'm answering this in case it helps someone in future.

```
[your-selector-goes-here] {
    perspective:1000px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to **also apply a null transform** ([3D layer promotion](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)) to the element that has `mix-blend-mode` specified:

```
.content {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

This way, Chrome can successfully blend the two 3D layers together, instead of failing to blend a 3D layer and a 2D layer.

Here's a snippet demonstrating the problem and the solution:

```js
function change(event) {
  var content = document.querySelector(".content")
  content.className = event.target.checked ? "content content-with-transform" : "content"
}
```

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: #AB1795;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background-color: #167CFB;
}

.content-with-transform {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
<label><input type="checkbox" onchange="change(event)"/> Also transform other element</label>
```

(I stumbled onto this problem when using `will-change: transform`, not an actual transform, but the solution is the same.)